# Logic question is it true

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Exercise:
$$\begin{align}
(\forall x>2) &~:~ |x|<3 \tag{P1}\\
(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(\exists\varepsilon > 0) &~:~-\varepsilon <x<\varepsilon  \tag{P2}\\
(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}) &~:~ x<n\text{ or } x+1\geq n  \tag{P3}\\
(\forall A>0)(\exists\varepsilon > 0)(\forall x>1)& ~:~x-\varepsilon<A\text{ and } x+\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}  \tag{P4} \\ 
(\forall A>0)(\exists\alpha>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^+) &~:~ x\geq A\implies x^2+1>A  \tag{P5}
\end{align}$$

Find $\neg P1,\neg P2...$ My answer

$$\begin{align}
(\exists x>2) &~:~ |x|\geq 3 \tag{not P1}\\
(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})(\forall\varepsilon > 0) &~:~ -\varepsilon \geq x\text{ or } x\geq\varepsilon \tag{not P2} \\
(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}) &~:~ x\geq n \text{ or }x+1< n  \tag{not P3}\\
(\exists A>0)(\forall\varepsilon > 0)(\exists x>1) &~:~ x-\varepsilon\geq A\text{ and } x+\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}  \tag{not P4}\\ 
(\exists A>0)(\forall\alpha>0)(\exists x\in\mathbb{R}^+) &~:~ x\geq A\implies x^2+1\leq A  \tag{not P5}
\end{align}$$

Is it true?

Comment: Try `\lor` and `\land` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. Recall the following. For $A=B\land C$ is the same as $\neg A=\neg B \lor \neg C$.

Then recheck $P3$ and $P4$.

Comment: P3 is false? I corrected P4

Comment: @user176840 Correct. Because $x+\epsilon$ need not be in $\mathbb{N}$ So $x-\epsilon\ge A \lor x+\epsilon\not\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: so my neg P3 is true?

Comment: @user176840 I'm sorry. I mixed up P3 and P4 in that last comment. In the current state of the question P3 is incorrect. The leaf should be $x\ge n \land x+1 < n$. Because of the negation of "and" being "or" that I talked about in the answer. And in the current state of the question P4 is incorrect for the reason in my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

For **P5**, note that $\lnot(A \Rightarrow B)$ is not the same as $A \Rightarrow \lnot B$

However $\lnot(A \Rightarrow B)$ is the same as $A \text{ and } (\lnot B)$

This is because $A \Rightarrow B$ is the same as $(\lnot A) \text{ or } B$

Comment: Okay corrected P5